# Retrieve rows even if value equal null

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to retrieve from database even if one of the fields has null

this is query

```
  @Query("{'origin.airport.iatacode' : ?0,'scores.value' : ?1,'carriername' : ?2,'scores.datetimedimension' : ?3}")
Set<Route> findByAll(String iatacode,Integer value,String carriername,String datetimedimension);
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/filter",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public Set<Route> gettome() {
    return routeRepository.findByAll("SOW", null, "Great Lakes Airlines", "201503");
}
```

this query filter Route collection depending on this values(iatacode,value,carriername,datetimedimension)

sometime one of this values or more than one has null ,so I need to filter with other values and ignore  values that have null.

Can any one help me to do that please or give me other idea to filter with available values?

Comment: You need to provide a sample of data to explain what you mean by "more than one has null". There is only one `null` being tested here and the other values supplied must all be an exact match so they cannot possibly match `null`.

Comment: the value my be like that  routeRepository.findByAll("SOW", null, "Great Lakes Airlines", "201503"); or routeRepository.findByAll("SOW", null, "Great Lakes Airlines", null); or routeRepository.findByAll(null, null, null, "201503"); etc

Comment: Those are just all separate calls and they will do exactly as asked. What I asked you is to "show some data" and "show and expected response" from a singular call, since you appear to be asking that, albeit in an abstract way. Please edit your question to explain more clearly.